# SecurityException when calling BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter

Tags: android, bluetooth, securityexception

In `onCreate()` of my app I call `BluetoothAdapter.getAddress()`. One single device of hundreds, that are running this app, yields a `java.lang.SecurityException`:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{xx.yyy.myapp/xx.yyy.myapp.RecActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH ADMIN permission: Neither
>   user 10095 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN.
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH ADMIN permission: Neither
>   user 10095 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN.
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379) at
>   android.bluetooth.IBluetoothManager$Stub$Proxy.getAddress(IBluetoothManager.java:295)
>   at
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getAddress(BluetoothAdapter.java:576)
>   at xx.yyy.myapp.RecActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source) at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   ... 11 more

As I can't debug on that device I would like to ask if the following solution is feasible or if there's a better way to handle the problem (this is the branch for less than JELLY_BEAN_MR2)?

```
BluetoothAdapter bta = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
try {
    macAddress = ( bta != null ) ? bta.getAddress() : "";
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    macAddress = "";
}
```

Also, I wonder if the Android version on that device might have a bug as it seems to me that `getAddress()` in [BluetoothAdapter.java](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java) doesn't require `android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`?

Or is it possible that the user with this device has a specific root tool to lock bluetooth access from my app? And that this might be the reason for the Exception?

Or what might be the reason for the problem?

Comment: Seems most likely that they have a root tool. Permission locking tools are becoming more popular and are included in many custom roms.

Comment: Do you know if my work around would catch the SecurityException and avoid the RuntimeException so that the app won't crash but continue to run?

Comment: [It's bad practice to write `catch(Exception e)` in most cases.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742940/why-not-catch-general-exceptions) Here, the `RuntimeException` is thrown separately by `ActivityThread` only if you don't catch the `SecurityException`, so it should be enough to just `catch(SecurityException e)`.

Comment: Thank you. As I can judge this is a significant part of the answer I was seeking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [it's bad practice to use `catch(Exception e)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742940/why-not-catch-general-exceptions), use

```
} catch(SecurityException e){
```

to prevent the crash.

(As an answer now instead of a comment.)