# How do I catch exceptions thrown by Eigen's MatrixXd::resize() function?

Tags: c++, exception, eigen

Why can't I catch this exception?

My (client) code:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd FFs ;
try
{
  FFs.resize( NUMPATCHES, NUMPATCHES ) ;
}
catch( int e )
{
  error( "Not enough memory :(" ) ;
  return ;
}
```

The Eigen code that throws the exception is a few levels down..

```
    EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void resize(Index rows, Index cols)
    {
        internal::check_rows_cols_for_overflow(rows, cols);
        m_storage.resize(rows*cols, rows, cols);
    }
```

Which calls

```
    void resize(DenseIndex size, DenseIndex rows, DenseIndex cols)
    {
      if(size != m_rows*m_cols)
      {
        internal::conditional_aligned_delete_auto(m_data, m_rows*m_cols);
        if (size)
          m_data = internal::conditional_aligned_new_auto(size);
        else
          m_data = 0;
        EIGEN_INTERNAL_DENSE_STORAGE_CTOR_PLUGIN
      }
      m_rows = rows;
      m_cols = cols;
    }
```

The bolded lines are the ones that get hit before the line:

```
throw std::bad_alloc();
```

gets hit, which happens somewhere inside the `internal::conditional_aligned_delete_auto(m_data, m_rows*m_cols);` function call.

Why can't I catch this exception from my client code?  Is it because the Eigen library didn't mark the `resize` function with `throws`?  How can I make this code using the Eigen library recover from this `malloc` type error smoothly?

Comment: Erm, because `catch(int)` can't catch a `std::bad_alloc`?

Comment: Well I should note that I never use C++ exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the exception being thrown by `resize()` was `std::exception`.  However, the code in the question explicitly tries to capture exceptions of type `int`.  This won't work and the `catch` block will be passed.

One way to fix this is by using a general "catch all" block:

```
try
{
  FFs.resize( NUMPATCHES, NUMPATCHES ) ;
}
catch(...) // catch all exceptions, no type declaration required
{
  error( "Not enough memory :(" ) ;
  return ;
}
```

The ellipses in the `catch(...)` statement mean you don't have to resolve exception type.  All exceptions will be caught, regardless of type.

However this appears to be not recommended.  [This may be analogous to the generic `catch( Exception e )` statements in Java and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426346/is-this-a-bad-practice-to-catch-a-non-specific-exception-such-as-system-exceptio), which is frowned upon in those languages for reasons stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426356/).

Comment: catch(...) will also catch all sorts of exceptions that are not normally thrown as a std::exception, like floating point exceptions, division by zero, page faults, etc. It can be very useful if you are calling code you don't fully trust (for example, a plugin) and you want to keep it from crashing your whole application if it does something nasty.

Answer (score 12):

You have to catch with the correct exception type. Use:

```
catch( std::exception &e )
```

instead of:

```
catch( int e )
```

Answer (score 8):

```
catch( std::bad_alloc& e) {
}
```

should help

Answer (score 6):

You are catching an exception of type `int`, while the actual exception being thrown is of type `std::bad_alloc()`.

```
catch (std::bad_alloc& e)
{
    exit(1); // or some other appropriate behavior
}
```

is probably what you want.