# Ruby method to begin method from begining?

Tags: ruby

Example(Rails):

```
def blabla

    @ads = ["1", "2"] if @ads.nil?
    @reklame = Reklamer.find(@koder.sample)
    @ads[0] = @reklame.id
    if @ads[0] == @ads[1]
    begin from start method from start
    end

end
```

Is there a method to restart the method/action so it begins from the top?

Comment: I suggest you think about this again, and try to use a `while` loop. Or a `loop` with a `break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the keyword `retry`, this keyword will restart the iteration from the beginning so consider to rebuild your method to use iteration, for example like this:

```
def blabla
  @ads = ["1", "2"] if @ads.nil?
  @ads.each_slice do |prev_,next_|
    @reklame = Reklamer.find(@koder.sample)
    prev_ = @reklame.id
    retry if prev_ == next_
  end
end
```

Also the keyword `redo` will repeat current iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ruby-goto](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/ruby-goto/) but I would definitely recommend against it.

For more information on why **not** to use goto statements check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274661/should-i-use-goto-statement).  It is C# based but I think it covers the point nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to accomplish, but it sounds like you need a loop of some sort. Would something like this do what you need?

```
def blabla
   @ads ||= ["1", "1"]
   # careful with comparing a string ("2") to a numeric id
   while @ads[0] == @ads[1] do
     @reklame = Reklamer.find(@koder.sample)
     @ads[0] = @reklame.id 
   end
end
```

Basically you keep reseting `@ads[0]` until it is different from `@ads[1]`.