# How can I generate random numbers between 1 and a number input by the user?

Tags: c++, random

How do I create a program that generates ten random numbers from 1 -> `RAND_MAX`?

`RAND_MAX` must be a number input by the user.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int x;
    int y;


    Random:
    {
        x = rand();
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    y = y + 1;
    if (y == 10) {
        return 0;
    }

    goto Random;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the program wouldn't appear, it should be there now, tough.

Comment: RAND_MAX is defined by std library http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random number c++ in some range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560114/random-number-c-in-some-range)

Comment: The question has already been answered, but I'd like to point out you need to initialise y otherwise you may find your program looping infinitely :)

Comment: @BenHymers I think that has already been done, (I think!).
It only generates ten numbers, but they are too big.
my if statement does that, I am pretty sure of it.

Comment: @Lemonizer y is assigned to (on the line `y = y + 1;`) but it's using its own value in that expression, and before that line is reached, it hasn't been initialised. The line `int y;` will probably set y to 0 in debug builds, but you can't rely on that. Run this in release and it will probably contain garbage, almost certainly more than the 10 that you're checking for, so you'll loop forever (or until y overflows!). You probably meant to write `int y = 0;`. Note that x is ok since you're assigning the result of `rand()` to it. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Random numbers uniformly over entire range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-entire-range)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** `rand` is a quick and dirty way to generate random numbers, as it may not generate numbers perfectly uniformly and you'll run into some issues if `RAND_MAX` (the upper limit for `rand`) is defined to be smaller than your target range. In modern C++ it would be better to use the `<random>` header, as per the question *[Generate random numbers uniformly over an entire range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288739/generate-random-numbers-uniformly-over-entire-range)*.

---

Something like:

```
int main()
{
  int randMax;
  cin >> randMax;
  for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
  {
    int x = rand() % randMax; // Range = [0, randMax)
    cout << x+1 << endl; // Range = [1, randMax]
  }
}
```

Oh, and do try to avoid `goto` (at least in my opinion). Here are [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379172/to-use-goto-or-not) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274661/should-i-use-goto-statement) about it.

Comment: Thank you!
But where exactly do I put this, and should it replace something? Also why can I not use "goto" ?
---Edit---
My only programming experience is with a TI-84, and I use goto all the time there, RandInt() is what its called on the TI
Calculators are so much simpler :P

Comment: And don't ever use capital letters for local variables.

Comment: this will not compile `RAND_MAX` is defined in the same header as `rand` and will be substituted by a number

Comment: Hmm, thank you for all your replies, but I don't see how the process can repeat ten times without goto.

Comment: @Lemonizer This code basically replaces everything. The for-loop causes it to repeat 10 times.

Comment: Thank you!
Well I have to say, generating random numbers was far more complicated than i thought. I looked at other two questions, but did not understand a thing. I tried to take a step away from my tutorial and try to duplicate some of the programs on my TI-84, but as said, it is very hard. I think I will return to my tutorial now.
Thank you everybody, if I ever make a game, I will name characters after you!

Comment: @chux Added a disclaimer.