# Can we use Try/Catch Within QueuedTask.Run()

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

Can we use Try/Catch within `QueuedTask.Run()`?

I have feeling that Try/Catch should be outside `QueuedTask.Run()` but I don't have reason for that. Please clarify whether to keep in or out of `QueuedTask.Run()`

```
public ICommand CmdEdit
{
    get
    {
        return _cmdEdit ?? (_cmdEdit = new RelayCommand(() =>
        {
            QueuedTask.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    if (_selectedObj != null && SelectedObjs.Count() == 1)
                    {
                        OnEditObj(_selectedObj);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    DialogService.ShowPrompt(ex, null, DialogServiceMessage.Message_EditError, DialogServiceCaption.Caption_Exception, DialogServiceButtons.Ok, DialogServiceIcon.Exclamation);
                    OneGeo.ExceptionLogger.EventLogger.Log(ex);
                }
            });
        }, () => (_selectedObj != null && _selectedObjs.Count() == 1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: Please elobrate on your feeling. Maybe you have actualy a different question? That said agree with above comment.

Comment: I am just thinking whether to use Try Catch outside QueuedTask.Run() or inside. How does this make a difference in execution? Please help here to understand difference keeping it outside or inside.

Comment: The only possible issue I see is calling DialogService.ShowPrompt() from a background thread. If it handles that correctly, then you're fine.

Comment: I am suggesting you literally try it out. Move the `try catch`. Purposely throw an exception. Compare how the two scenarios act. To be clear **I know what will happen**. I am trying to teach you to fish.

Comment: Thanks but i just left workplace. It would be great if u can let me know “What will happen” as you already know being an expertise

Comment: You can't interact with any UI element from a non-UI thread. Showing a dialog is then out if you're in a task.

Comment: Also, don't do `catch (Exception ex)` - it's a bad anti-pattern. You should only ever catch **specific** exceptions that you can **meaningfully** handle.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a reason to handle it outside, then it is okay to handle it inside. You should always handle exceptions as soon as you can handle it correctly. So I would go for inside.

I have no domain knowledge about ArcGIS, but if `QueuedTask.Run` can throw it's own exceptions (exception which are not generated by your delegate), you wouldn't catch them this way. However, you should handle that seperate anyway.

Also you need to consider, `QueuedTask.Run` seems like an `async` operation. So to be able to catch any Exception you need to `await` it before. If you can't, you definitive need to catch it inside.

So the definitive answer: It depends. It could also be a context decission as [glenebob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391812/can-we-use-try-catch-within-queuedtask-run#comment89755724_51391812) commented:

> The only possible issue I see is calling `DialogService.ShowPrompt()` from a background thread.

On a side note: You should use catch all exceptions only as a last resort. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426346/is-this-a-bad-practice-to-catch-a-non-specific-exception-such-as-system-exceptio).